# Convergence of $\sum (-1)^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{n} + (-1)^{n+1}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I want to determine whether the following series is convergent or not and prove it:
$\sum (-1)^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{n} + (-1)^{n+1}}$

After graphing the series, it looks to be divergent. Additionally, I have tried to apply Abel's test and didn't manage to show convergence. I am not aware how to prove that this series is divergent, as the only tests that I am aware of that can show divergence are comparison and LCT, but neither work for series with negative numbers.

The following necessary condition of convergence is true, so it can't be used:

$\text{lim } (-1)^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{n} + (-1)^{n+1}} = 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed divergent. We can group adjacent terms together to get
\begin{align*}
\sum (-1)^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{n} + (-1)^{n+1}} =& \sum \frac{-1}{\sqrt{n}+1} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}-1} \\
=& \sum  \frac{\sqrt{n} - \sqrt{n+1} + 2}{\sqrt{n^2+n} + \sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n} - 1}
\end{align*}
For $n$ large enough, every one of these terms is larger than $\frac{1}{n-1}$, and hence the series diverges.

Comment: Can we group adjacent terms like this when they have different signs?

Comment: So long as they are adjacent, yes, but we musn't mess with the order of summation.

Comment: But, I mean it you can't group together the terms in a series like the following: $\sum (-1)^n$, as grouping adjacent terms would give you $\sum 0$, but this is obviously false as this series is not convergent. Or do you mean that this can be only used for showing divergence?

Comment: Yes. Looking at the series as a sequence of finite sums, we show that there exists a divergent subsequence, and hence the sequence cannot be convergent.

Answer (score 1):

$u_{2n}+u_{2n+1}= ({1\over  \sqrt {2n}-1}-{1\over \sqrt {2n+1}+1})={a_n\over b_n}$

with $a_n=\sqrt {2n+1}+1- \sqrt {2n}+1=2+\sqrt {2n} (1+{1\over 4n}+o(1/n)-1)=2+o(1)$, and $b_n \sim {1\over 2n} $. Therfeore $u_{2n}+u_{2n+1} \sim {1\over n}$, and the series is divergent.